# Select a ribbon tab Ribbon.read with a button

Tags: development, javascript, ribbon

My question is simple:

How do I select a ribbon.read with javascript? For example i have a different tab selected but clicking on the button i would like to select Ribbon.read ... any adivces?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but this code should select the Ribbon.Read

```
var ribbon = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon();
SelectRibbonTab("Ribbon.Read", true);
```

Comment: yeah, i tried that but i dont get the instance of ribbon it is undefined, also if i use the function: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded with parameter sp.ribbon.js

Comment: is get_instance or get_ribbon undefined?

Comment: it says SP.Ribbon.PageManager is null or not an object

Comment: Even SP.Ribbon is undefined :(

Comment: Looks like you don't use the correct namespace then (SP.Ribbon) ;-)

Comment: Which should i use then? i tried with CUI.Page.PageManager.get_instance() and i get there an instance, but i dont get the ribbon, when i do get_instace().get_ribbon() i get null

Comment: Don't use CUI.Page, try to use SP.Ribbon instead. You also have to reference the correct files, try it as described in this [link](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2011/09/09/manipulating-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript-part-1/)

Comment: yeah, ill try but i think the reference is wrong, but although i use the default master page

Comment: Do you have a reference to sp.ribbon.js which should be in the _layouts folder?

Comment: i suppose so, but even in the site which you gave me the guys is not adding reference to sp.ribbon ...

Comment: ok i added the reference to sp.ribbon.js and i got the get_instance() BUT the get_ribbon returns still NULL

Comment: does the get_ribbon function exist in the file you referenced? Maybe you should create a new question (with code) so we don't get too long comment section, because this seems to be a different question than before.

Comment: at the end i foxed it

Comment: Good to hear that :-) May I ask how you solved the problem?

Comment: Look [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/143330/6962) for a more complete solution.