# Always show SP2013 Ribbon across SharePoint

Tags: office-365

I am using Office 365 SharePoint site and I would like to set the ribbon to always be visible.

When I go to a document library its hidden by default, when I select a file two tabs show 'Files' and 'Library' I then have to click on one of the tabs to see the commands in the ribbon

I would like it so when I go to any libraries /lists the ribbon is visible and I can see the commands.

[image]

How would I do this?

EDIT = Script editor with code

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

try{
  var tabs=document.querySelectorAll("li[role='tab']"),    //all tabs, see mum, No jQuery!
  tabid=tabs[1].id,    //second tab
  tabname=tabid.split('-title')[0];    //disregard the last part of the id
  console && console.info('opening tab:',tabname);
  SelectRibbonTab(tabname);    //standard SP function from init.js 
}
catch(e){}    //ignore any errors, sloppy coding but SP also uses this all over the place

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

All tabs are identified by names like `Ribbon.Read` `Ribbon.WikiTabPage`;
you can check the HTML source

Pages, TaskList, List, Library Tabs all have different names

This code (I did not include the wait for pageload) just opens the second tab:

```
try{
 var tabs=document.querySelectorAll("li[role='tab']"),//all tabs, see mum, No jQuery!
     tabid=tabs[1].id,//second tab
     tabname=tabid.split('-title')[0];//disregard the last part of the id
  console && console.info('opening tab:',tabname);
  SelectRibbonTab(tabname);//standard SP function from init.js 
}catch(e){}//ignore any errors, sloppy coding but SP also uses this all over the place
```

If you want more advanced interactions with the Ribbon:

- [How to collapse Ribbons bar when page is loaded?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143292/how-to-collapse-ribbons-bar-when-page-is-loaded)
- https://sharepoint247.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/javascript-to-hide-or-select-specific-tabs-in-sharepoint-ribbon/
- http://rishiigupta.blogspot.nl/2015/07/enable-ribbon-on-item-selection-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but where do I put this code?

Comment: Anywhere you want it executed, a CEWP on page for one page, in your MasterPage for every page, or with CSR, spent a weekend [learning JS+SP](https://www.google.nl/search?q=include+javascript+sharepoint&oq=include+javascript+sharepoint&aqs=chrome..69i57.4336j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I have added a script editor webpart and added the code but nothing happens, see my original posts for screenshot

Comment: If you do not have a JavaScript drivers license I can not drive the car for you. [Learn how to add (and debug) executing JavaScript on SP pages](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+run+on+page&tbs=qdr:y&tbo=1&as_oq=sharepoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=-0l1VtDPK8fzO924jNAN)

Comment: I clearly do not know anything about javascript, posting half an answer is not very helpful

Comment: You are free to ignore it.